# Can not access filed values from base class

Tags: java, class, reflection

I have a base class in Java named A And a derived class name B.
I want to access the values of the private or public variables of B from A(base class).
I can read the variable names but not variable value with this code:

```
protected void loadValues()
    {
        Field[] fields = this.getClass().getDeclaredFields();
        for(Field field:fields){
            try {
                xLog.info(field.getName()+"-"+field.get(this).toString());
            } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

The error is:
access to field not allowed.

I can do it in C# easily. how can I do this in java?
Here is the way I'm doing it in C#:

```
   private void loadValues()
    {
        foreach (var item in GetType().GetFields())
        {
            Type type = item.FieldType;
            object value = item.GetValue(this);
            fields.Add(new Tuple<string, Type, object>(item.Name, type, value));
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use `field.setAccessible(true);` before accessing the field.

Example:

```java
public static class A {
    public void test() throws Exception {
        Field[] fields = this.getClass().getDeclaredFields();
        for (Field field : fields) {
            field.setAccessible(true);
            System.out.println(field.getName() + "-" + field.get(this).toString());
        }
    }
}

public static class B extends A {
    private String foo = "bar";
    public B() throws Exception {
        super();
        test();
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    new B();
}
```

Prints:

```
foo-bar
```

Comment: a little problem remains yet, if foo have no variable an execption will be thrown. how to handle this?

Comment: @ehsanshirzadi What do you mean by *no variable*? Do you mean no value set? In this case, you have to check that `field.get(this)` does not return `null`.

Comment: It was my mistake, I mean no value. If you do not have a value in FOO, an exception will be thrown.

Comment: Yes, a `NullPointerException`, because you're using `.toString()` on the returned value. You have to check that `field.get(this)` does not return `null` before calling `.toString()`.

Answer (score 5):

Do `field.setAccessible(true);` before reading from that field.

And also **really really think again** before implementing a cyclic dependency like this in Java. Is it really the best solution to your problem to invert inheritance like this?

Reflection is a powerful tool, but usually has the smell of a rather unclean solution.

Comment: Would you please give me a solution for my purpose? I want to have classes for my entities containing only the fields not methods for INSER,UPDATE. I want to create INSERT,UPDATE methods in base class using the fields and values of derived class. do you have any solution or recommendation for this purpose?

Comment: How about composition for this purpose? An entity should not insert/update itself. A persister class could do that for every entity (use reflection there, or use an existing persistance framework, maybe Hibernate based on JPA). This would free up your entities to have real inheritance relationships, should you need those. Keep in mind that Java does not support extending from several base classes.